# Blocking external users from using dns

Tags: domain-name-system

I have two DNS servers ns1(master) & ns2(slave). It is working alright.. My requirement is like I dont want any external users to use my dns servers, therefore for that reason I have provided ACL in named.conf file using my network IP ranges. But at the same time I need that if I make a reverse lookup request from the website 'www.mxtoolbox.com' using my DNS IP addresses, it should get the PTR.

But I saw that when I add 0.0.0.0/0 IP range in the ACL, then and then only it is working.. otherwise it gives an error "Sorry, we couldn't find any name servers for 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.in-addr.arpa'"

Comment: Posting your config will help.

Comment: Operating System and DNS server details would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

How about rather than blocking all access just restrict the use of recursion (i.e. allow-recursion { xxx/xx }; ) ?